# Linearly Independence & Ortogonality of Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[0 1; 1 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKlDa.png)

Hello, I have a doubt about the orthogonality of eigenvectors. Here, if we find the eigenvectors of the matrix, we can get (1,j) and (1, -j). For the orthogonality, all the properties say that the inner product of two matrixes should be equal to zero but if we apply inner product to these eigenvectors, we get 2. However, the solution manual says that these eigenvectors are orthogonal. Am I wrong or there is a mistake in the book? Also how can we proof that these eigenvectors are linearly independent? Thanks.

Comment: For vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ the correct inner product is $z\cdot w = \sum z_i \bar w_i$.

Comment: So what should I do to calculate the inner product sir? What is the ¯ symbol up on the wi? Can you explain it in more details? Thanks.

Comment: If $z=a+bj$ is a complex number, $\bar z = a-bj$. It is known as complex conjugation and reverses the sign of the imaginary part of $z$.